# Почему не работает realpath кэш в режиме веб?

Tags: php, php.ini

Обнаружил, что `realpath_cache_get()` всегда пустой, начал разбираться и выяснил, что в режиме cli все работает отлично, а вот при запросе из веб получаю пустой массив.

Из скрипта:
    `<?php realpath(null); var_dump(realpath_cache_get()); // array(0) {}`

Из консоли:
    `php -r 'realpath(null); var_dump(realpath_cache_get());' // array(5) {...}`

Сравнить полностью `phpinfo()` из веб и cli трудно из-за разных форматов, но основное одинаково:

```
ini_get('open_basedir'); // bool(false)
ini_get('realpath_cache_size '); // string(5) "2048k"
ini_get('realpath_cache_ttl '); // string(3) "120"
```

Версия php на сервере только одна:

```
PHP 5.6.25 (cli) (built: Aug 31 2016 19:17:57)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

При запросе из веб `realpath_cache_get()` очень редко проскакивает `/etc/php.d/opcache-default.blacklist`, а в основном, массив пустой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что если в httpd.conf хотя бы для одного домена указан open_basedir, то realpath кэш не будет работать вообще ни для одного домена. Из cli, разумеется, httpd.conf не обрабатывается.

В итоге для себя решил проблему с помощью php-расширения [turbo_realpath](http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/07/12/running-php-on-nfs-version-1-2-of-turbo_realpath-extension/).